# JQuery hover efect not starting on first hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a menu that I want to animate on hover to slide down an sub menu.

Problem with this is that on first hover menu doesn't slide down, just on second and all after that until page is again initialized. 
In example code you you can see the behavior, to see the first hover not taking effect just press run again. I have read few articles here and none of it makes sense to me and I can not relate to any of them.

Been trying for hours now so any help or guidance is welcome. 
Also bonus* sub menu dos not actually slide up, but I can live with that...

```js
$(function () {    
  $('.stranke').hover(function () {
    $('.stranke-d', this).stop(true, true).delay(100).slideDown(300);
  }, function () {
    $('.stranke-d', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(300);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"> 
<div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-mobile  stranke">
                <button class="w3-button  meni-divider draw" >STRANKE <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-dark-grey meni-round w3-center dropdown-stranke" style="box-shadow:0 6px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40), 0 6px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40)">
                    <a href="unos-strankep-forma.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile meni-divider meni-round draw  stranke-d">UNOS NOVE</a>
                    <a href="strankep.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile meni-divider draw  stranke-d">PRAVNE</a>
                    <a href="strankef.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile meni-round meni-divider draw  stranke-d">FIZIČKE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your initial html and the html after the first slideDown/slideUp is that after the first time, all the elements have a `style="display: none"` on them.  If you initialize the html with that inline style, it works from the get go.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.stranke').hover(function() {
    $('.stranke-d', this).stop(true, true).delay(100).slideDown(300);
  }, function() {
    $('.stranke-d', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(300);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-mobile  stranke">
  <button class="w3-button  meni-divider draw">STRANKE <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
  <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-dark-grey meni-round w3-center dropdown-stranke" style="box-shadow:0 6px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40), 0 6px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40)">
    <a href="unos-strankep-forma.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile meni-divider meni-round draw  stranke-d" style="display: none">UNOS NOVE</a>
    <a href="strankep.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile meni-divider draw  stranke-d" style="display: none">PRAVNE</a>
    <a href="strankef.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile meni-round meni-divider draw  stranke-d" style="display: none">FIZIČKE</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was actually trying that but looks like in wrong way, or something else was wrong, I got lost in process. Thank you very much. Any ideas maybe on slide up? Its not that important, I appreciate the help so far.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When I remove mouse it does not slide up, it just goes to display none.  slideUp does not takes effect.

Comment: @ikiK not entirely sure what is going on there.  you may want to open another question about that.  My first thought is that the `w3.css` file is applying some weird styling rules for when not focused.

Comment: Ok, Ill try to look into it myself first, thanks for all the help.

Comment: You where right, .w3-dropdown-content had class on cursor display one, it was removing menu before js, had to override it. It works now. Thanks once more.