# Function doesn't happen with the first click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to JS, and I've got a problem with my slides. It works okay, but not from the first click. I've written a console log in the function and it is shown with the first click, but the if/else statement starts working with the second click. I don't understand the problem.

```
let index = 0;

function previousPage () {
    console.log ('previous');
    initialize();
    if (index === 0){
        index = spContainer.length;
        spContainer[index-1].style.display = 'flex';
        index--;
    } else {     
        spContainer[index-1].style.display = 'flex';
        index--;
    }
}

function nextPage () {
    console.log ('next');
    initialize();
    if (index === spContainer.length){
        index = 0;
        spContainer[index].style.display = 'flex';
        index++;
    } else {
        spContainer[index].style.display = 'flex';
        index++;
    }
}

function initialize () {
    spContainer.forEach (x => x.style.display = 'none');
}
```

Comment: this might be the issue of `event bubling` so please try ` event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: your index is starting at 0 but on your first previousePage you are accessing the element `spContainer[index-1]` which is the `-1-th` element which doesnt exist

Comment: You have to set first .style.display  in CSS or inline in order to work from start. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61546021/7158959

Comment: But, I first make it ' === container.length', then i access it.

Comment: It may also be a problem related to variable initialization, have you checked that both index and spContainer have the values you want? It would be useful to print those values after the console log

Comment: Yes it looks like they have the same values.

Answer (score 0):

You have `let index = 0;`. Then you are selecting `spContainer[index-1]` which is `undefined`.

Comment: But I first make it,  index === spContainer.length. Then i access index-1.

Comment: 3 equal signs? You need to use one for changing value of a variable.

Comment: My mistake. In the code, it's one =. The problem can't be there. I guess..

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things by having just one function that goes forward or back via a parameter. This way the logic is done once and can be tested reliably. You can determine the new index value then set its display value just once. To move to the next page call `movePage(true)` and for previous page call `movePage(false)`.

The way you had the code working the `index` value was being changed **after** the flex was set and the wrong element might stay selected. The code below is more straight forward and should be less confusing to test/debug. The key is to setting the right `index` value **before** setting the `display` style to 'flex`.

```js
const spContainer = [{style: {}},{style: {}},{style: {}}];
let index = 0;

function movePage(forward) {
    spContainer.forEach (x => x.style.display = 'none');
    index += forward ? 1 : -1;   // move index up or down by one
    if (index < 0) {
        // if negative, go back to end of list
        index = spContainer.length - 1; 
    } else if (index >= spContainer.length) {  
        // if past the end go back to zero   
        index = 0;
    }
    spContainer[index].style.display = 'flex';

    console.log (forward?'next':'previous',index);
    console.log(spContainer);
}

function nextPage() { movePage(true); }
function previousPage() { movePage(false); }

previousPage(); // previous will go to index 2 from index 0
nextPage();     // next will go back to start (index 0)
nextPage();     // next again will go to index 1
```

Comment: This looks complicated to me... but i've added these functions to next prev buttons, as a click event. How can i add this to 2 different buttons? sorry if my question is too stupid :)

Comment: You can still have nextPage and previousPage functions if you like. The example is updated. I like having just one function for handling the move since duplication of code often leads to hard to fix bugs.

Comment: Also you can get rid of the need for the initialize function since it's only ever called once.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your comparison here is wrong - `if (index === spContainer.length) {}`, it should be `if (index === spContainer.length - 1) {}` since length starts from 1 and index - from 0.

I also don't really understand how you can run `forEach` with `spContainer`. It shouldn't be possible.

But I would suggest you to rebuild the whole logic in a bit different way. Like this:

```
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"); // grab all your slides here
let index = 0;
const maxIndex = slides.length - 1;

function increaseIndex() {
  if (index === maxIndex) {
    index = 0;
  } else {
    index++;
  }
}

function decreaseIndex() {
  if (index === 0) {
    index = maxIndex;
  } else {
    index--;
  }
}

function hideAllSlides() {
  for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

function render() {
  slides[index].style.display = "flex";
}

function switchToPrev() {
  hideAllSlides();
  decreaseIndex();
  render();
}

function switchToNext() {
  hideAllSlides();
  increaseIndex();
  render();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: If i make it index === container.length -1, then it skips the last item, because the index of the last item is 2. So when the index is container.length, aka 3, then i make index = 0. This makes sense. No? When the index is bigger than 2, it becomes 0.

Comment: Yes, but you should be comparing CURRENT index against the next one. So if current index is "slides.length - 1" (last item), the next one should be 0 (first item). I still don't understand what your `container` is coming from. Could you explain the way you grab all slides? I would still recommend to take a closer look at my code above since it's clear and easier to extend. At the same time, I would suggest to start learning MVC patterns - they completely changed my JS code years ago.

Comment: @YuriyVasilyev Her comparison isn't wrong.. the order in that she does things is wrong. If she would first increase index and than check if it is out of bounds, that would work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not update `index` before you use it:

```js
spContainer[index].style.display = 'flex';
index++;
```

Let's say `index = 0`. Hence the element `spContainer[0]` is displayed when the page is loaded.

With the first click you change the `display` property of element `spContainer[0]` to `flex`, which is already `flex` since `index` is still `0`. You can't see any changes because you didn't make any changes at all.

Then you update `index` with `index++` to `1`

Now with the second click you change the `display` property of element `spContainer[1]` to `flex`, because `index` has been updated to `1` with the previous click.

Just make sure to update `index` before you use it:

```
let index = 0;

function previousPage () {
    console.log ('previous');
    initialize();
    if (index === 0){
        index = spContainer.length - 1; 
    } else {
        index--;
    }
    spContainer[index-1].style.display = 'flex';
}

function nextPage () {
    console.log ('next');
    initialize();
    if (index === spContainer.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
    } else {
        index++;
    }
    spContainer[index].style.display = 'flex';
}

function initialize () {
    spContainer.forEach (x => x.style.display = 'none');
}
```